# sqlite db exception : Could not open database

Tags: android, sql, android-sqlite

Following error is comming while running my application :

```
'/data/data/in.acme.www.solarproject/databases/SolarDatabase.sqlite'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:807)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:792)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:697)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:672)
            at in.acme.www.solarproject.database.DBHelper.checkDataBase(DBHelper.java:81)
            at in.acme.www.solarproject.database.DBHelper.createDataBase(DBHelper.java:49)

    try{
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);  // (DBHelper.java:81)

    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        //TODO: Add exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

i had copied my db to assets folder, from their i query for the getDbrecords()

```
SQLiteDatabase mReadableDB= mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
try{
    mCursor=mReadableDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM DepartmentMaster ",null);
```

from there exception is comming .Please help to resolve it .

Comment: i has copied SolarDatabase.dp from assets and opened it in sqlite expert , and make select query, its working fine . I did not understand the problem.

Comment: You need to copy the database (programmatically) from the `assets` folder to the data folder (`/data/data/your.app.name/databases/`), if it doesn't already exists. Or to the storage (internal or external). You can't open the db directly from `assets`.

Comment: from asset to application path , i am doing programmatically .  After getting problem , i copied db from asset -> paste to some other path -> then opened it from sql expert -> to check it is corrected or not .

Answer (score 0):

Few things you could try:

1. Try opening it with [SQLiteBrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) to see that it's not corrupt
2. Make sure it's in the right path
3. Ensure it has the right permissions for read/write
4. Ensure you have this permission in your manifest file `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Comment: i has copied SolarDatabase.dp from assets and opened it in sqlite expert , and make select query, its working fine in sql expert . and i have write permission , Initially it was working fine, then i had to done some changes in Tables design , and copied again db to asset folder , cleared previous data so my new db will copied to "/data/data/in.acme.www.solarproject/databases/" path , Now db is created at this path but its not opening .but it can be opened in other s/w .